# How to make a call to a API so that it returns whatever you're requesting and how to reduce the amount of watchers in Vuejs

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

In my code as you can see I'm making a call to an api that returns a link, but there are other things that I want from the api, so how would i modify the function so I can get something like the title of an anime from the api or the list of episodes that it has
Also if i do get the title or the list of episodes, won't i have to start watching more things? Is there a way around this?

```js
<template>
  <section class="container">
    <div class="column">
      <img :src="url1" alt="./assets/notFound.png" />
    </div>

    <div class="column">
      <img :src="url2" alt="./assets/notFound.png" />
    </div>
  </section>
</template>

<script>
import axios from "axios";
import Buefy from "buefy";
import "buefy/dist/buefy.css";
import Vue from "vue";
Vue.use(Buefy);

export default {
  props: {
    anime1: String,
    anime2: String,
  },
  data() {
    return {
      url1: "",
      url2: "",
      error: "",
    };
  },
  methods: {
    animeFind(anime, data) {
      axios
        .get(`https://api.jikan.moe/v3/search/anime?q=${anime}`)
        .then((response) => {
          const id = response.data["results"][0]["mal_id"];
          axios
            .get(`https://api.jikan.moe/v3/anime/${id}`)
            .then((response) => (this[data] = response.data["image_url"]));
        })
        .catch((error) => {
          this.error = error; // take care of this later
        });
    },
  },

  watch: {
    anime1: {
      immediate: true,
      // eslint-disable-next-line no-unused-vars
      handler(newVal, oldVal) {
        this.animeFind(newVal, "url1");
      },
    },
    anime2: {
      immediate: true,
      // eslint-disable-next-line no-unused-vars
      handler(newVal, oldVal) {
        this.animeFind(newVal, "url2");
      },
    },
  },
};
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all :
To find out the result of the api you are consuming,
you can

```
axios
    .get(`https://api.jikan.moe/v3/search/anime?q=${anime}`)
    .then((response) => {
      const id = response.data["results"][0]["mal_id"];
      axios
        .get(`https://api.jikan.moe/v3/anime/${id}`)
        .then((response) => {
           console.log(response)
         });
    })
```

after you console.log() your response try seeing the result in your browser console
after that you can get all the data you want using reponse keys

```
this.key = response.data.[key]
```

don't forget to add the keys you are looking for in your data object

```
data() {
return {
  url1: "",
  url2: "",
  key1: "",
  key2: "",
  error: "",
};},
```

Comment: Okay but don't i need watchers that? How would I get the title from the API to be printed then